# ReactJS re-render does not reset input fields

Tags: reactjs

Building input elements into a table and loading the elements with data ala a CRUD grid.  It was my understanding that when a react state signals a re-render of the page that all the elements are re-rendered.  In my test case, I am using `defaultValue` to give the inputs their data value; however when the state changes (ie I reorder the array) the values do not change for the inputs.

Code SandBox [TestCase](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-smoke-pxylh?file=/src/App.js)

Note that when you click a Move Up Button the actual array is reordered but not reflected in the grid.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState([
    { recordid: 1, companyname: "Devshare", contactname: "Joeann Rechert" },
    { recordid: 2, companyname: "Shufflebeat", contactname: "Lazare Kubiczek" },
    { recordid: 3, companyname: "Mita", contactname: "Jordain Copyn" }
  ]);

  const moveRecordUp = (e) => {
    e = e.target || e;
    let row = parseInt(e.getAttribute("data-row"));
    let nGridData = gridData;
    let holdRow = nGridData[row];
    nGridData.splice(row, 1);
    nGridData.splice(row - 1, 0, holdRow);
    setGridData([...nGridData]);
  };

  console.log(gridData);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {gridData.map((r, rndx) => {
        return (
          <div key={rndx} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <input defaultValue={r.companyname} value={r.companyname} />
            <input defaultValue={r.contactname} />
            {rndx > 0 && (
              <button data-row={rndx} onClick={moveRecordUp}>
                Move Up
              </button>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please also add the relevant code here. It makes it easier for whoever looks at the question to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No problem, just seemed like a lot of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered previously , the issue is occuring because you need to use the `value` prop in both the `input` elements for the changes to reflect. And for your concern of making the `input` editable `onChange` prop is required . You can try using this approach :-

```
  const handleChange = (e: any, rndx: number, changingVariable: string) => {
    const value = { ...gridData[rndx], [changingVariable]: e.target.value }
    const arr = [...gridData]
    arr[rndx] = value
    setGridData(arr)
  }
```

```
            <input
              defaultValue={r.companyname}
              value={r.companyname}
              onChange={(e) => {
                handleChange(e, rndx, 'companyname')
              }}
            />
            <input
              defaultValue={r.contactname}
              value={r.contactname}
              onChange={(e) => {
                handleChange(e, rndx, 'contactname')
              }}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your issue is that `defaultValue` sets only the initial value of the input. You should set the `value` of the input to `r.companyName` as well:

```
<input defaultValue={r.companyname} value={r.companyname}/>
<input defaultValue={r.contactname} value={r.contactname}/>
```

Comment: on the 2nd line you should have `value={r.contactname}`

Comment: Yes; however,  I don't want the input to be controlled.  Putting the "value" attribute in the input does not allow me to type in the field.

Comment: hmm.. that's interesting. You may be able to update the DOM with a useEffect because it seems like the `gridData` actually changes behind the scenes.